# How do I delete all files with a certain extension in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, file-management

A while ago I turned my laptop (Windows 8) over to "Geek Squad" to fix a few minor issues. When I got it back, I found many folders in my drive with some sort of placeholder file in each of its sub-folders.

Rather than asking Geek Squad about it or dealing with it right away, I recently attempted to fix it with a Command Prompt entry [*del /s *.gwqa*], suggested for Windows 7. Instead of rapidly deleting all of the files, it just made the files invisible to the Command Prompt function. I understand fairly little about computers, but that seems irreversibly inconvenient, without the right program.

Comment: Maybe they have just enabled the display of hidden and/or system files in explorer, unchecking that mark might hide the unwanted files again.  (I am not familiar with Win8, it will be somewhere on the explorer tab or preferences menu)

Comment: Geek Squad strikes again.

Comment: No, If I check Hidden Items under the View Tab, those system files are faded while the placeholder files appeared with "unknown file type" icon, and took 0 bytes of space. Maybe the guy missed a step in packing up after his fix attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Computer and write `*.[extension]` (i.e. `*.jpg`) in the search bar. This should give you a list of all files of the specified extension.

Comment: Thanks! That's 9075 +backupDrive bits of clutter gone. I wonder what the Command Prompt was doing..